# Add tabs in a View Pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs

How I can add tabs to swipeView fragments?

Here is the onCreate method of the main activity in which the two fragments are initialized:

```
  MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;


/**
 * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
 */
ViewPager pager = null;
MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Instantiate a ViewPager
    this.pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Set a custom animation
    this.pager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPagerTransformer());

    // Create an adapter with the fragments we show on the ViewPager
    this.adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    this.adapter.addFragment(InActivityPageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.red), 0));
    this.adapter.addFragment(ListActivitiesPageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.white), 1));
    this.pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: `PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is your friend ;-)

Comment: Well I understood your question by how to add new Fragment-tabs inside a ViewPager dynamically. So when you add them, invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()`. If you're searching for a way to add tabs in general and don't know how, see here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html